# Can an Explosive Missile be aimed at the ground for splash damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

The Explosive Missile discovery explains clearly that the missile doesn't detonate if it misses (and if I understand correctly, this cannot work as a touch attack unless you use a firearm at close range, what defeats the purpose of the feat as far as I can tell). What about intentionally shooting at the ground instead of trying to hit a specific target ? Does the infused ammo detonate and deal splash damage to enemies around, or does it really need to hit something specific ?

Answer (score 8):

That's a nice tactic that is perfectly valid. The ground is a target and this is not a spell that only lets you target "creatures" or something like that. Of course, this means that nobody will take the primary damage of the bomb, just the splash damage. Easier target, minor effect looks fair to me.

Comment: What happens on a natural 1? You shoot the ground in front of your feet, taking splash damage yourself?

Comment: Natural ones are critical fails but don't have to becatastrophic. Chaos of combat, you or the bow is bumped right when you release and it ends up pointed up farther... or if you are up for some potential antics that come from a nat 1... straight up. 1 or 2 rounds before the arrow lands ... somewhere? Or they nocked the arrow the wrong way and the fletching hits the handle on the release skewing it. That is a very rookie error. Or drop the arrow, fire the wrong arrow (hits the ground and nothing happens... cause its just a regular arrow.)

Comment: @JesseCohoon natural 1 = automiss. The bomb does not explode. Nobody gets hurt. Not hitting the target is bad enough, there's no need for random disgraces.

Comment: Does that mean the enemy is now in possession of a bomb?

Comment: @Harper: alchemical bombs stop functionning if someone who is not the alchemist who created them take them, so the enemy is now in possession of a vial of weird stuff that does nothing.